# jQuery datepicker stays open after focus set through code

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Here is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g5ouLxqu/) with problem.

I am looping through all input elements, setting focus. When done, last datepicker stays open.

HTML:

```
<input id="id1" type="text" class="datepicker" />
<input id="id2" type="text" class="datepicker" />
<input id="id3" type="text" class="not-datepicker" />
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
  });  
});

$("input").each(function() {
    $(this).focus();
});
```

How do I close it?

**UPDATE**

Adding screenshot from Chrome on Mac, it does work fine on Firefox. As you can see focus is on 3rd input element, yet second input is showing datepicker.

[image: screenshot from Chrome on Mac]

Comment: could you please provide your instantiation code?

Comment: updated question to include all the code from the jsfiddle.

Comment: I am on latest Chrome on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

JqueryUi auto-closes the datepicker when an element loses focus by user interaction.  You can add a callback to hide the datepicker, or destroy it.

- Hiding it: $('.datepicker').hide();
- Removing it entirely: $(".datepicker").datepicker('destroy');

Worth noting- if you destroy it, you'd need to reinstantiate for further user to be able to make further changes/select again.

Comment: `$('.datepicker').hide()` hides whole input. This is probably what you were thinking: `$('.datepicker').datepicker("hide");`. But that flickers. Anyway. Thanks.